# Three.js: Casting shadows

Tags: three.js

I'm working with Three.js r88 and though I tried following the documentation's example for adding shadows with a PointLight [[docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/lights/shadows/LightShadow)], I must be missing something. Here's my scene:

```js
  /**
  * Generate a scene object with a background color
  **/

  function getScene() {
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x000000);
    return scene;
  }

  /**
  * Generate the camera to be used in the scene. Camera args:
  *   [0] field of view: identifies the portion of the scene
  *     visible at any time (in degrees)
  *   [1] aspect ratio: identifies the aspect ratio of the
  *     scene in width/height
  *   [2] near clipping plane: objects closer than the near
  *     clipping plane are culled from the scene
  *   [3] far clipping plane: objects farther than the far
  *     clipping plane are culled from the scene
  **/

  function getCamera() {
    var aspectRatio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspectRatio, 0.1, 1000);
    camera.position.set(0, 1, -30);
    return camera;
  }

  /**
  * Generate the light to be used in the scene. Light args:
  *   [0]: Hexadecimal color of the light
  *   [1]: Numeric value of the light's strength/intensity
  *   [2]: The distance from the light where the intensity is 0
  * @param {obj} scene: the current scene object
  **/

  function getLight(scene) {
    // SHADOW
    var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1, 100 );
    light.position.set( 0, 10, 0 );
    light.castShadow = true;            // default false
    scene.add( light );

    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
    scene.add(ambientLight);
    return light;
  }

  /**
  * Generate the renderer to be used in the scene
  **/

  function getRenderer() {
    // Create the canvas with a renderer
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    // Add support for retina displays
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    // Specify the size of the canvas
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    // SHADOW
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
    // Add the canvas to the DOM
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    return renderer;
  }

  /**
  * Generate the controls to be used in the scene
  * @param {obj} camera: the three.js camera for the scene
  * @param {obj} renderer: the three.js renderer for the scene
  **/

  function getControls(camera, renderer) {
    var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.zoomSpeed = 0.4;
    controls.panSpeed = 0.4;
    return controls;
  }

  // Render loop
  function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    controls.update();
  };

  var scene = getScene();
  var camera = getCamera();
  var light = getLight(scene);
  var renderer = getRenderer();
  var controls = getControls(camera, renderer);

  //Create a sphere that cast shadows (but does not receive them)
  var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry( 5, 32, 32 );
  var sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } );
  var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial );
  sphere.castShadow = true; //default is false
  sphere.receiveShadow = false; //default
  scene.add( sphere );

  //Create a plane that receives shadows (but does not cast them)
  var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 50, 20, 32 );
  var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xffff00, side: THREE.DoubleSide})
  var plane = new THREE.Mesh( planeGeometry, planeMaterial );
  plane.receiveShadow = true;
  scene.add( plane );

  render();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
  canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
```

```html
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/88/three.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js'></script>
```

Does anyone know what I can do to make the shadow render? I'd be grateful for any suggestions others can offer on this question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your point light is resting on the same plane as your plane. This results in the shadow calculations going to infinity/NaN.

Moving the light  even slightly toward the camera causes the shadow to calculate correctly. In the below snippet, I change the light's position's Z component from `0` to `-1`, and got a shadow.

```js
/**
  * Generate a scene object with a background color
  **/

  function getScene() {
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x000000);
    return scene;
  }

  /**
  * Generate the camera to be used in the scene. Camera args:
  *   [0] field of view: identifies the portion of the scene
  *     visible at any time (in degrees)
  *   [1] aspect ratio: identifies the aspect ratio of the
  *     scene in width/height
  *   [2] near clipping plane: objects closer than the near
  *     clipping plane are culled from the scene
  *   [3] far clipping plane: objects farther than the far
  *     clipping plane are culled from the scene
  **/

  function getCamera() {
    var aspectRatio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspectRatio, 0.1, 1000);
    camera.position.set(0, 1, -30);
    return camera;
  }

  /**
  * Generate the light to be used in the scene. Light args:
  *   [0]: Hexadecimal color of the light
  *   [1]: Numeric value of the light's strength/intensity
  *   [2]: The distance from the light where the intensity is 0
  * @param {obj} scene: the current scene object
  **/

  function getLight(scene) {
    // SHADOW
    var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1, 100 );
    light.position.set( 0, 10, -1 );
    light.castShadow = true;            // default false
    scene.add( light );

    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
    scene.add(ambientLight);
    return light;
  }

  /**
  * Generate the renderer to be used in the scene
  **/

  function getRenderer() {
    // Create the canvas with a renderer
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    // Add support for retina displays
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    // Specify the size of the canvas
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    // SHADOW
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
    // Add the canvas to the DOM
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    return renderer;
  }

  /**
  * Generate the controls to be used in the scene
  * @param {obj} camera: the three.js camera for the scene
  * @param {obj} renderer: the three.js renderer for the scene
  **/

  function getControls(camera, renderer) {
    var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.zoomSpeed = 0.4;
    controls.panSpeed = 0.4;
    return controls;
  }

  // Render loop
  function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    controls.update();
  };

  var scene = getScene();
  var camera = getCamera();
  var light = getLight(scene);
  var renderer = getRenderer();
  var controls = getControls(camera, renderer);

  //Create a sphere that cast shadows (but does not receive them)
  var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry( 5, 32, 32 );
  var sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } );
  var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial );
  sphere.castShadow = true; //default is false
  sphere.receiveShadow = false; //default
  scene.add( sphere );

  //Create a plane that receives shadows (but does not cast them)
  var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 50, 20, 32 );
  var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xffff00, side: THREE.DoubleSide})
  var plane = new THREE.Mesh( planeGeometry, planeMaterial );
  plane.receiveShadow = true;
  scene.add( plane );

  render();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
  canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/88/three.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js'></script>
```